# Ruby get last * in a string

Tags: ruby

I have a string with different data and stars as well. How can I get the index of the last *?
For example

```
hello * there * *
```

Now how can I get the index of the 3rd *?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [String.rindex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-rindex):

> Returns the index of the last occurrence of the given substring or
>   pattern (regexp) in str. Returns nil if not found.

```
x = 'hello * there * *'
puts x.rindex('*') # 16
```

Comment: `#rindex`, nice method that I forgot about.